# Extrair informação específica de uma célula de excel usando pandas no Python

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, pandas, pyautogui

Preciso extrair uma informação de uma célula em excel usando pandas e pyautogui. A célula tem uma data contida e preciso tirar os números sem as barras "/". Exemplo: 25/12/2000.

O que faço no momento é olhar o que o usuário digitou na célula data de nascimento e separo manualmente na planilha os números 25, 12 e 2000 em outras 3 células (dia mes ano)e utilizo o pandas pra acessar essas 3 células e consigo o efeito desejado, como acesso direto com pandas a celula **data de nascimento**?

Hoje eu ajusto manualmente e separo a data em 3 células e busco a informação nessas celulas

Minha Planilha:

```
          A           B                  C                 D     E     F #transformo a celula C em D, E e F
1        nome     sobrenome      data de nascimento       dia   mes   ano
2        Joao       Mendes          25/12/2000            25    12    2000
```

Quero uma função que busque a informação de dia, mês e ano da Célula **data de nascimento** e me traga essa informação 1 de cada vez e não todas de uma vez.

```
import pyautogui import pandas as pd

formulario = pd.read_excel(r'C:\formulario.xlsx', sheet_name='Planilha1')
## Uma amostra de dados para teste...
#formulario = pd.DataFrame({
#  'nome':['João'], 
#  'sobrenome':['Mendes'] , 
#  'data de nascimento': ['25/12/2000']
#})

for i in range(1):
        pyautogui.write(str(formulario['dia'] [0]))
        pyautogui.write(str(formulario['mes'] [0]))
        pyautogui.write(str(formulario['ano'] [0]))
```

Resolvido:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'data de nascimento': ['25/12/2000']})

data = df['data de nascimento'] [0]
dia = data[:2]
mes = data[3:5]
ano = data[6:]

print(dia)
print(mes)
print(ano)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para a partir de uma coluna contendo datas de nascimento em *string* no formato `dd/mm/yyyy` para a separar em colunas contendo dia, mês e ano dessa data:

1. Usando um *DataFrame* de similar estrutura ao da pergunta....

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame({
  'nome':['João', 'Maria', 'Daniel'], 
  'sobrenome':['Mendes','Tavares', 'Cunha'] , 
  'data de nascimento': ['25/12/2000', '21/03/1999', '22/10/1981']
})
```

2. Como os dados na coluna `data de nascimento` estão em formato string crie uma coluna temporária `data` onde receberá a conversão dos dados na coluna `data de nascimento` usando o método [`pandas.to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

```
df['data'] = pd.to_datetime(df['data de nascimento'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

3. Crie as colunas `dia`, `mês` e `ano` em outro *DataFrame* com auxilio das propriedades [`Series.dt.day`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.month.html), [`Series.dt.month`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.month.html) e [`Series.dt.year`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.year.html) e junte ao *DataFrame* original usando o método [`DataFrame.join()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html).

```
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame({
  'dia': df['data'].dt.day, 
  'mês': df['data'].dt.month, 
  'ano': df['data'].dt.year
}));
```

4. Remova a coluna temporária `data` como o método [`DataFrame.drop()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)

```
df = df.drop(columns=['data'])
```

5. Cujo o resultado:

```
print(df)

     nome sobrenome data de nascimento  dia  mês   ano
0    João    Mendes         25/12/2000   25   12  2000
1   Maria   Tavares         21/03/1999   21    3  1999
2  Daniel     Cunha         22/10/1981   22   10  1981
```

## EDIT:

Parece que o usuário tem dificuldades em ler os dados das colunas de um DataFrame. Existem várias possibilidades uma delas é [`DataFrame.iterrows`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) que faz a iteração nas linhas de DataFrame como pares (índice, linha).

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
  print(f'Registro: {i + 1}')
  print(f'Nome: {row["nome"]}')
  print(f'Sobrenome: {row["sobrenome"]}')
  print(f'Dia : {row["dia"]}')
  print(f'Mês : {row["mês"]}')
  print(f'Ano : {row["ano"]}')
  print('-'*30)
```

Saída:

```
Registro: 1
Nome: João
Sobrenome: Mendes
Dia : 25
Mês : 12
Ano : 2000
------------------------------
Registro: 2
Nome: Maria
Sobrenome: Tavares
Dia : 21
Mês : 3
Ano : 1999
------------------------------
Registro: 3
Nome: Daniel
Sobrenome: Cunha
Dia : 22
Mês : 10
Ano : 1981
------------------------------
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@RonaldoVasques/DateSplit#main.py)</sup>

Comment: Eu quero usar os dados da 'data de nascimento' e não criar 'dia' 'mes e 'ano'. Quero algum comando que leia apenas o dia, depois o mes e depois o ano e que possa imprimir isso no programa.

Comment: Dê uma outra olhada no [exemplo](https://replit.com/@RonaldoVasques/DateSplit#main.py) fiz uma modificação e veja se é isso que quer fazer.

Comment: Consegui resolver assim:

`import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'data de nascimento': ['25/12/2000']})

data = df['data de nascimento'] [0]
dia = data[:2]
mes = data[3:5]
ano = data[6:]

print(dia)`